# C# if statement always returning false

Tags: c#

I have an if statement in a web service call that is always returning false. I want it to return an error message if there isn't the words "VERTICALPALLETS", or "PALLETLABELS" in it. Even if this field has those words in it, it is still returning an error. The query is not the correct one I am using in my application. Any help is much appreciated.

```
public bool ValidateDevice(string DeviceID, string sVersion, out string MachineID, out string MachineName, out string Plant, out string Printer1, out string Printer2, out string WrapStation, out string Location, out string sMessage)
{
    MachineID = "";
    MachineName = "";
    Plant = "";
    Printer1 = "";
    Printer2 = "";
    Plant = "";
    WrapStation = "";
    Location = "";
    sMessage = "";


    bool bTest = CheckVersion(sVersion, out sMessage);
    if (bTest == false)
    {
        sMessage = "You do not meet the minimum version requirements. Contact MIS.";
        return false;
    }


    try
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(capmSADPConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        string queryString = "select * from DATABASE";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DEVICEID", DeviceID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APPID", "VTP");

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows == false)
        {
            email myEmail = new email();
            myEmail.SendErrorEmail("No Application Settings for VTP Device ID - " + DeviceID, "VTPError", "VTP Device Settings Error");
            sMessage = "Could not find application settings for this device. Please enter settings.";
            return false;
        }




        reader.Read();

        MachineID = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
        MachineName = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
        Plant = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
        Location = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
        Printer1 = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
        Printer2 = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
        WrapStation = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();

        reader.Close();
        reader = null;
        command = null;
        connection.Close();
        connection = null;

        if ((Location.ToUpper().Contains("VERTICALPALLETS") == false) || (Location.ToUpper().Contains("PALLETLABELS") == false))
        {
            sMessage = "Please enter correct location in Application Setup and try again.";
            return false;
        }



        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        sMessage = "Unable to retrieve Application Settings for VTP. Please reopen the application.";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So .. you want to throw an exception?

Comment: you need logical and && to get the condition you described: "if there isn't the words A OR B": `if(s != "A" && s != "B")` will be true if s matches neither.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by logical and &&? Edit: I see what you're talking about!

Comment: `if (Location.IndexOf("VERTICALPALLETS", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) < 0 && 
    Location.IndexOf("PALLETLABELS", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) < 0) {...}`

Comment: `a == false` is only (slightly) useful for `bool?`. For normal use, get used to `! a`

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I was able to get it working by using '&&' rather than '||'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is with the structure of your `if` statement:

```
if ((Location.ToUpper().Contains("VERTICALPALLETS") == false) || (Location.ToUpper().Contains("PALLETLABELS") == false))
{
    sMessage = "Please enter correct location in Application Setup and try again.";
    return false;
}
```

You are saying:

```
If the location does not contain 'VERTICALPALLETS'
Or Else
If the location does not contain 'PALLETLABELS'
```

This will always be true unless the location contains both bits of text!

You need to change the `Or Else` to `And Also` (so `||` to `&&`) and therefore your code will work as expected.

Comment: Ah I guess my brain just doesn't want to work this morning! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use AND

```
if ((Location.ToUpper().Contains("VERTICALPALLETS") == false) && (Location.ToUpper().Contains("PALLETLABELS") == false))
```

Alternative solution which is simpler to read.

```
if (!(Location.ToUpper().Contains("VERTICALPALLETS") || Location.ToUpper().Contains("PALLETLABELS"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the problem is that you'll always be looking for a "false" or "false" condition unless you are looking for a location that contains both  VERTICALPALLETS PALLETLABELS

I suggest you try something like

```
if (! ( condtion1 || condition2) )
 return message
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if ((Location.ToUpper().Contains("VERTICALPALLETS") == false) || (Location.ToUpper().Contains("PALLETLABELS") == false))
```

checks whether `Location.ToUpper()` does not contain "VERTICALPALLETS" or `Location.ToUpper()` does not contain "PALLETLABELS". If `Location.ToUpper()` does not happen to contain both, then the condition is true. You instead wanted to check whether `Location.ToUpper()` contains either of them:

```
if ((Location.ToUpper().Contains("VERTICALPALLETS") == false) && (Location.ToUpper().Contains("PALLETLABELS") == false))
{
    //...
}
```

also, it does not makes much sense to calculate `ToUpper` several times, let's calculate it only once:

```
String upperLocation = Location.ToUpper();
if ((Location.ToUpper().Contains("VERTICALPALLETS") == false) && (Location.ToUpper().Contains("PALLETLABELS") == false))
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: @AndrewReese you are welcome. If any of the answers answered your question, then please select the best one as the correct answer.